# How to convert captured image to GIF and save to sd card in android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-image, android-camera-intent

I am using custom camera and i want to capture 3 images in burst mode and save it to sd card as a animation. which has extension as .gif and combines that 3 captured frames in it.
Also want to save the image capture time in database.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use ImageMagick? It is free and available [here](http://www.imagemagick.org). It has a set of command-line tools and also bindings for Perl, Java, PHP, C++, Python, Ruby etc.

If so, just do this to convert all jpegs in the current folder into an animated GIF:

```
convert -delay 20 -loop 0  *.jpg  animated.gif
```

ImageMagick is available for Android.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For database work

```
      ImageHandling ih = null;
       ih = new ImageHandling(this);
      ih.getBitmapAsByteArray(R.drawable.imgename); 
      insertData(ih.getBitmapAsByteArray(R.drawable.imgename));
      private void insertData( byte[] bitmapData){
       values.put("imagename", bitmapData);
        }
```

and then finally

```
      public class ImageHandling {

Resources res;
Activity activity;
public ImageHandling(Activity a) {
    activity = a;
    res = a.getResources();
}
private Bitmap getBitmapFromResource(int resourceId){

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resourceId);
    return bitmap;
}   

public byte[] getBitmapAsByteArray(int resourceId){
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = null;
    byte[] bitmapByteArray = null;
    try {
        outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromResource(resourceId);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputStream);
        bitmapByteArray =  outputStream.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        if(outputStream != null){
            try {
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    return bitmapByteArray;
}}
```